# Finite Element analysis: distribution of sine wave over a distance

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, finite-difference-method

I am trying to solve the following one-dimensional problem:

(to better understand and extend the FEM for a more complex problem),

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

f = 1000;
x0 = 1;
e = 2;
l = 100;
d = 10;

u[x_] = x0 Sin[(2*\[Pi]*f) * x];

ufun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x], {x}] == (e/l) d u'[x],
u[0] == u[x], u[1] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}];


Plot[ufun[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

The output is supposed to be an exponential function. @x=0 I am applying a sine wave and @x=1, the value is zero, (which I can't figure out how to do it). Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: What do you mean by "@x=0 I am applying a sine wave"? Have you mixed up `t` and `x`? Can you show us the equation you're trying to solve with traditional math notation?

Comment: @xzczd ∇^2 u=ε/(l d)  (du/dt) , ε=constant value, l=100, d=1. so I am trying to get distribution of u(x) across the distance x.

Comment: …So you've mixed up `t` and `x`. The equation should be `Laplacian[u[t, x], {x}] == e/(l d) D[u[t, x],t]`. And this is a spatially 1D problem i.e. 1+1D problem. There're many related examples in document and this site, please read them carefully.

Comment: @xzczd oh I see, if possible can you share any example or documents, so, I know that I am looking at a right example.

Comment: Reading examples in document of `NDSolve` and `DSolve` by pressing F1 should be quite enough for your problem. For more advanced introduction see e.g. PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/HeatTransfer.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, I am afraid what I mentioned before for the first time and in the question is fine. The solution to that equation is simple harmonic oscillator equation, but I was trying to see, if I could solve the problem from FEM Mathematica. So, basically I have a length of x (0, 10) and @ x=0 I applied voltage of 1 volts and @x=1 the voltage is zero (let's say "+" and "-"). So, the equation I mentioned in the comment is wrong, the derivative is ∇^2 u=ε/(l d) (du/dx), (I transformed from frequency domain to time domain, so, made a mistake).

Comment: In the next step I would have ∇^2 u=ε/(l d) (du/dt)  and now u is a function u(x,y) and at the end distribution of u from one end to other end as well, let's say for a rectangular sheet.

Answer (score 3):

Almost:

```
f = 1000;
x0 = 1;
e = 2;
l = 100;
d = 10;
uBC[x_] = x0 Sin[(2*\[Pi]*f)*x];
ufun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[u[x], {x}] == (e/l) d u'[x], 
    u[0] == uBC[0], u[1] == 1}, u, {x, 0, 1}];
Plot[ufun[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

You'd need to rename your boundary condition function to uBC and evaluate that at 0. I also changed the second BC, as the first is also 0 at x=0 and that makes for an uninteresting solution.